# Dart, stdin.readLineSync();

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I'm new in world of dart and I have problem with this:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
void main() {
  print('Please your name:');
  String name = stdin.readLineSync();
  print('$name');
}
```

```
I/flutter ( 7962): Please your name:

I/flutter ( 7962): null
```

Every time the value is null.

[image]

Comment: cant see you did type your name on terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  print('Please your name:');
  String? name = stdin.readLineSync();
  print('$name');
}
```

Comment: : Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
lib/main.dart:5
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.12 or higher.
  String? name = stdin.readLineSync();
        ^ 
Do I need to change the langauge version?

Comment: change the language version and try it again

Comment: It's a problem with a Visual Studio Code, because on a IDEA it's everything ok. I thank You for help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please use this code and let me know about the result :

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
   print('1 + 1 = ...');
   var line = stdin.readLineSync(encoding: utf8);
   print('$line');
}
```

Comment: When I used your code I had the same problem. But it's a problem with a Visual Studio Code, because on a IDEA it's everything ok. I thank You for help.

Answer (score -1):

the value cannot be null , just add the question mark

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Stdin/readLineSync.html

modify this line and normally is done
String? name = stdin.readLineSync()!;

Comment: Your answer is wrong. you should remove the `!` at the end of the line! Also put your code in code block. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).